# Is it correct to say "I associate my ringtone with a headache"?

Tags: collocation

The idea is that it is very annoying and I'm tired to hear the same tune over and over again. Please see the full sentence where the phrase is used below:

> Aren’t you tired of your old boring ringtone that you almost associate with a headache?

Comment: "...you almost associate with a headache" sounds odd. I'm not sure how you can "almost associate" something.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you seem to be describing is that the ringtone *gives* you a headache.  Every time you hear that sound, your head hurts.

It does make sense to *associate* a ringtone with a headache, but that would describe a different situation: Every time I talk on the phone, I get a headache.  Therefore, whenever I hear the ringtone and I think of talking on the phone, I'm reminded of having a headache.

Comment: Yes. "That ringtone gives me a headache" is more the idiom one might hear - but spoken hyperbolically of course. Ring tones don't really give people headaches. Staying indoors in a dry environment, and not drinking enough, definitely does.